# how add the list of strings into string using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, string, list

I have List consists of `{"a","b","c"}` i have string s contains`{"alphabets"}` .i like to add the list to string. i need final output in s like this `{"alphabetsabc"}. i like to do this using linq.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using LINQ, or even [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx), would be overkill in this case. [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat.aspx) will do the trick nicely:

```
string s = "alphabets";
var list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };

string result = s + string.Concat(list);
```

(Note that if you're not using .NET4 then you'll need to use `string.Concat(list.ToArray())` instead. The overload of `Concat` that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't exist in earlier versions.)

Answer (score 5):

Why not just [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx)? Using Linq would be an overkill.

Comment: And `Join` itself would be overkill when you can use `Concat`!

Answer (score 2):

Quick & dirty:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() {"a", "b", "c"};
string s = "alphabets";

string output = s + string.Join("", list.ToArray());
```

Comment: In .NET4 they finally added an overload to string.Join that takes an IEnumerable of string. As such .ToArray would be superfluous.

Comment: Using `Join` is overkill in this case. What's wrong with `Concat`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat.aspx

Comment: Nothing wrong with Concat just Join was the first thing that came to my mind :)

Answer (score 1):

You need the [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx) method, if you *really* want to use LINQ.